# How to disable NVIDIA card on Centos 7

Tags: boot, nvidia, gui

I have a NVIDIA card on my cenots 7 desktop. After running some updates, after a KDE install, it stopped booting the gui (the screen just freezes). Is it possible to remove the NVIDIA card and use the onboard graphics instead. 
I checked the xorg.conf file. There is an entry for NVIDIA under `Section 'Device'` however I am not sure whether commenting the lines would produce the desired effect, since no onboard VGA is present.

The actual error from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` causing the graphic card problem is

```
[    17.005] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[    17.005] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[    17.005] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[    17.007] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[    17.007] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[    17.007] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[    17.007] (EE) No devices detected.
[    17.007] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    17.007] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[    17.007] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    17.007] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    17.007] (EE)
[    17.007] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

Yes. you can remove the NVIDIA graphics card and use the onboard graphics chip, if one exists by default on your motherboard. But, you've mentioned there is no onboard `VGA` chip.

`xorg.conf` is just a software protocol to make use of the hardware graphics chip to create GUI space. Deleting/commenting the NVIDIA related entries under `xorg.conf` will lead to undesirable effects especially, if you don't have a onboard graphics chip.

The reason why your `KDE` freezes may entirely due to some software related issue/bug. It is not advisable to change the hardware just because your update broke your system.

What I would do is, boot into `single user` mode and check whether it is an issue of the desktop manager(in your case KDE) or Xorg itself.

**Follow-up**

From your error stack, it seems your update has updated your kernel too. If your NVIDIA driver has not been installed from your distributions repositories then you manually install your NVIDIA driver and load it as a module. You may need to recompile the kernel depending on your setup.

Comment: Well it is rather strange, because I have no `BusID` listed for the NVIDIA card in `xorg.conf`

Comment: If you have no other graphics chip in your motherboard you don't need bus ID to be specified.

Comment: Well it stops at `Started Crash recovery kernel arming.d stops the USB Arbitrator`

Comment: Can you please add the error trace in your original question. So in future it would make sense to everyone.

Comment: I included the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Comment: Got it little later. Apologies. Please ignore my comment.